# Cómo instalar php 7.1 servidor Nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx

Resulta que tengo un servidor Nginx UBUNTU, y un viejo compañero me instalo el php 5.6 y el 7.0 para que pudiese utilizar los dos, dado que hay proyectos viejos que son dificiles de actualizar.

Bien ahora quiero instalar `composer` y luego el laravel `5,7` pero necesita el PHP 7.1, intente seguir un tutorial pero da errores todo el rato. No se si al tener varias versiones de php tengo que hacer algo diferente.

Error al ejecutar `sudo apt-get install php7.1`

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-139-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-139- 
generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-141-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-141- 
generic but it is not going to be installed
linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-141-generic but it is 
not going to be installed
php7.1 : Depends: libapache2-mod-php7.1 but it is not going to be installed or
               php7.1-fpm but it is not going to be installed or
               php7.1-cgi but it is not going to be installed
      Depends: php7.1-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Comment: ¿qué errores aparecen? ¿qué comandos intentas? necesitamos toda esa información.

Comment: salen miles de errores jajjaja, sigo este tutorial ---https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/install-php-7-1-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-16-04-vps/

Comment: voy a intentar pegarte todo @Shaz pero salen muchas cosas... :(

Comment: Editada @Shaz , puse el error que marca al intalar

Comment: Ahí está lo que sugiere hacer: `apt-get -f install`

Comment: Ya lo hice pero no soluciona nada :( Es como si saliesen errores al actualizar ubuntu entiendo

Comment: También parece que tenga problemas de espacio en el disco